# Stepper motor stalls at high RPM

Tags: raspberry-pi4, stepper

I'm using a raspberry pi 4 8GB with a DRV8825 driver to run the stepper motor, the stepper motor is a NEMA 17 rated at 1.7 A. The problem is that the stepper motor can't run at high RPM's. I have managed to get the motor to 600 RPM with a delay of 0.00025 (4th argument) between each step (code below). However, when I decrease this value to 0.00015 for example (this is supposed to give 1000 RPM) the motor stalls. How do I stop the motor from stalling. I've tried increasing the current using the potentiometer on the drv8825 driver, nothing happens.

The code that I'm using:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from RpiMotorLib import RpiMotorLib
import time


direction_x = 22 # Direction (DIR) GPIO Pin
step_x = 23 # Step GPIO Pin
EN_pin_x = 24 # enable pin (LOW to enable)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(EN_pin_x,GPIO.OUT) # set enable pin as output
GPIO.output(EN_pin_x,GPIO.LOW)# pull enable to low to enable motor

mymotortest_x = RpiMotorLib.A4988Nema(direction_x, step_x, (21,21,21), "DRV8825")


while True:
    mymotortest_x.motor_go(True, "Full", 100000000, 0.00025, False, 0.0005)
```

1st argument - boolean value, controls the clockwise (False) or counterclockwise (True) motion of the rotation 2nd argument - controls the stepping increment based on the DRV8825 MS1-MS3 values. The 0-1 value of each of the MS1-MS3 values controls the stepping increment following the specification in the table below:
[MS1-MS3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwOqb.png)

So for my code (full step) the ms1 - ms3 values should be set to 0. 3rd argument - controls the number of steps to take. 4th argument - controls the delay between each step. 5th argument - controls the printout of debugging information of the RpiMotorLib. 6th argument - the initial delay before the motor control begins.

For further information the article for the wiring and further detail is here.

Comment: Every stepper motor will stall beyond a certain drive frequency, that's just how it is. Also the current through a stepper motor is limited by the applied voltage; eventually the current will go into saturation since the driving voltage does not suffice to overcome the back-electromotive-force (BEMF), so you'd have to increase the driving voltage as well. Now you're probably driving that thing in full step mode, which is rather poor in performance. Ideally you'd use some microstepping mode, but that is virtually impossible to do by driving GPIOs (you'd need phase aligned PWMs for that).

Comment: Why is using a full step poor in performance? And I can use a microstepping mode by changing the 2nd argument as described in the question. The power supply I'm using is 12V, I'll try and get a power supply which has a higher voltage rating

Comment: Microsteps give you a more consistent torque along a full cycle, whereas in full step mode the torque is pulsing; between phases with high torque there are phases with almost no torque at all in full stepping mode. It is in these low torque phases where a stepper motor will stall.

Comment: Oh, and before I forget: It's also important to drive proper velocity ramps. Starting at a high frequency right from the start will always lead to some steps being lost at the start. Ideally you'd drive a starting-jolt free ramp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29#In_motion_control

Comment: So I should slowly speed up the stepper motor when it starts instead of cranking it all the way to the final speed?

Comment: Yes, acceleration and velocity ramps are very important.

Comment: I managed to upgrade to a 19v, 3.16A power supply, but at a delay of 0.00025 between each step (worked smoothly with the previous power supply) results in the stepper motor stalling after a couple steps, then continue to work, then stall again